# C# Saving integer to another method for the next use

Tags: c#, loops, methods

I'm working on a program that can transfer your Arm Angles to a Mindstorm Robot for a while now. But my main problem at the moment is that the robot motors don't know any start Point where the angle is 0 degrees. So i had the idea to write an algorithm that will do that. The problem is that i can't do it with a loop cause the robot is trying to suicide when he is getting to much commands at one time. 
So now I have the idea to save the "old angle i" to another method.
I'm not sure if that is the best way to do it, so I was wondering what you people would say i should do. Is there a way to "save" it in this method without using a loop ?

Here is my code :

```
private void RobotMove(int RobotArmR) //RobotArmRight from another method
    {

        int i = 0;
        int k = RobotArmR * 3; // Real time angle *3 for the gear wheel
        int j = k - i; // Real time angle - old Angle 
        i += j; 
        int sign = Math.Sign(j);
        // Depends on sign if the motor is moving right or left
        switch (sign)
        {
            case -1://Motor right

                    McNxtBrick brick = new McNxtBrick(NxtCommLinkType.USB, 0);
                    McNxtMotor motor = new McNxtMotor();
                    brick.MotorA = new McNxtMotor();
                    brick.Connect();
                    j *= -1;
                    UInt16 l = Convert.ToUInt16(j);
                    brick.MotorA.Run(20, l); // (Power Right 50, angle to move back or foward to get to the new angle)
                    brick.Disconnect();
                    break;

            case 1: //Motor left

                    McNxtBrick brick2 = new McNxtBrick(NxtCommLinkType.USB, 0);
                    McNxtMotor motor2 = new McNxtMotor();
                    brick2.MotorA = new McNxtMotor();
                    brick2.Connect();
                    UInt16 l2 = Convert.ToUInt16(j);
                    brick2.MotorA.Run(-20, l2); // (Power left 50, angle to move back or foward to get to the new angle
                    brick2.Disconnect();         
                    break;


            case 0:

                break;

        }
    }
```

Thanks for the tipps :)

Comment: Save in other method? How could you possibly save something into a method? Also, you can remove your switch and use math.sign().

Comment: It's more a design question, than a specific problem solving one. Variables are used to store things. You use variable when you want to store something: local variable, private variable, static ones, etc. It's not clear how exactly robot works, but more likely where are several commands and you want to ensure what all of them are sent one after another, which sounds like organizing *queue* to me. Moreover, your communication class can have something on top of it to hold *device state*, so that you can query what last command did, what is the current *angle*, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a helper class just for saving global variables' values, as public static ones, like bellow:

```
public class MyHelper
{
    public static int MyVal {get; set;}
}
```

and somewhere in your main method, initial the value

```
MyHelper.MyVal = 0;
```

and of course, you can use it anywhere, e.g.

```
MyHelper.MyVal++;
```

Comment: As a quick solution - yes, as a general workaround - no.

Comment: surely there are other alternatives as well, could you name another one? @Sinatr

Comment: Sure, how about *device status* class on top of *device communication* one with **non static** properties . My comment is mostly due to chosen name - `MyHelper`, which sounds like general storage for all kind of variables to become a complete mess and nightmare very soon.

Comment: @Sinatr you're truly right, but it's obvious Csharpo Darpo wanted something like `static` variables in methods, as in C++, which has been removed from C#.